# Problem with a simply search by a select element in Angular

Tags: html, angular, http

sorry for my bad english, i have a problem with a research by a select option. It's a search where i have to find a lists of tv series by genre(optional) and if they are suitable for minors or not. At the first i want to use a checkBox that would return a boolean value to do the get request, but i saw that it's impossible pass a boolean value in the URI, it's true?

For this reason i used a select element with two costant strings(suitable and unsuitable) and i want to do the get request by query string. But, there is an error that i don't understand.

This image explain the error that i have using the browser console. The italian part in the image was translated it's an old screen that i did.
[Error console code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTZRJ.jpg)

This is the html code for the select:

```
<select class = "form-select" formControlName=suitableOrNot">
                <option value={{costants.SUITABLE}}>{{costants.SUITABLE}}</option>
                <option value={{costants.UNSUITABLE}}>{{costants.UNSUITABLE}}</option>
            </select>
```

This is the code of the formGroup of the search form

```
formSearchTvSeries = new FormGroup({
    genre: new FormControl<string|null>(null),
    suitableOrNot: new FormControl<string>('',Validators.required)
  });
```

And this is the code of the DAO that i used for the http request.

```
getUserTvSeries(userId:number, genre:string|null, suitableOrNot:string):Promise<TvSeries[]>{
    let url = environment.backendUrl + '/lists-tv-series?userId=' + userId + '&suitableOrNot=' + suitableOrNot;
    url += genre ? "&genre=" + genre + '&' : '';
    console.log('Url:', url);
    return lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<TvSeries[]>(url));
  }
```